# Python catching a wrapped C function error

Tags: python, c, cython, python-c-api

When calling a wrapped c function as such:

```
f = io.BytesIO()
with stdout_redirector(f):
    r = _wrapped_c_function(in_file, out_file)
```

the return code is returned in `r`, where return codes are given based on the errors raise inside the C function, however if an error occurs in the C function that is NOT caught by the C function `r` exits as 0 and the Python program silently exits as 0 indicating as if nothing was wrong. However in stdoutt a message such as `malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)` will get printed.

How can I catch these error messages, as the function call should print nothing if it all works. The issue with using the redirector is that when `_wrapped_c_function` fails it exits the Python function before anything can get written into the buffer `f`.

Comment: Either you are breaking the C function's contract or the C function is buggy. If the former, you should check your arguments before passing them. If the latter, you should not try to fix it on Python's side.

Comment: The function is buggy, but I want to raise an error when the case is that the C function is buggy. However currently I can't catch the unknown cases when the C function is buggy as it just silently exits!

Comment: Log the function call.  If the function fails, you will know because you'll see it get called in the log but no return value or error.

Comment: The C function isn't handling the error condition from malloc failing correctly. There's nothing you can do about that without patching the C code.